# aurelia-configuration not found after jspm aurelia-configuration install

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I tried to install [aurelia-configuration](https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration) according README file using the **jspm**.

But i got this message:
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/vheissu/aurelia-configuration@1.0.7.js 404 (Not Found)

This file really missing in this folder. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration/issues/43.

Comment: Author here. I will be putting out a new release for this plugin hopefully today which will fix the issue.

Comment: @DwayneCharrington Yeah, I'm still getting this.